# Rails undefined local variable when rendering partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, slim-lang

I have a piece of code that renders one of two partials like this (I use slim-lang):

```
- case restream.service
- when 'youtube'
  = render partial: 'youtube', locals: { provider: restream.provider }
- when 'custom'
  debug = restream.provider
  = render partial: 'custom', locals: { provider: restream.provider }
```

In both `_youtube.slim` and `_custom.slim` I just call smth like `p = provider.name`. Moreover, "custom' was created by copy-pasting code from 'youtube'. However, while rendering Rails throws an error: `undefined local variable or method 'provider' for #<#<Class:0x00564028bb89d8>:0x007f92d3d0fa80>`

Trying to resolve this issue I just renamed `_custom.slim` to `_custom1.slim` and changed a call to `= render partial: 'custom1', locals: { provider: restream.provider}` and that worked!

Can anyone, please, explain, how does it works and what's wrong with 'custom' name? Is it a reserved name?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe there is a partial file also named _custom, but with different extension, maybe _custom.html.slim or any other like this. So when you render partial: 'custom', it may render the partial which is not you want.